# Magento CMS page continuously loading with blank page

Tags: cms-pages, magento-1.14, loading

Magento EE 1.14 contentiously loading with blank page but all html script available in view source.

Is any one have the solution for this

[image]

Comment: Please share screenshot.

Comment: @DineshRajput, Added in question

Comment: check-in var/log file ?

Comment: Don't have any error in exception log

Comment: Try uncommenting `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in **index.php** and check if you get any error details on the page.